# Drawing Simple Bar Charts in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qquickwidget

Using Qt/C++ for a normal widget application, and the `QQuickWidget` with QML, how would I draw a simple bar chart like the following?

[image]

I guess this question goes back to how the QML would be composed.

Comment: Have you tried writing any QML yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These instructions are for Mac OSX. You will have to vary this slightly for Windows or Linux:

1. In a Qt/C++ widget-based application, add the **QQuickWidget** to your **MainWindow** and set it to around 500x500 size. Don't set the Source property on that widget.
2. In your **.pro** project file, adjust your `QT` parameter to include `quickwidgets`. Also, add the following to the bottom of this file:

```
mac {
  Resources.files = objects
  Resources.path = Contents/MacOS
  QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += Resources
}
```

3. Create an **objects** folder inside your project folder as a general purpose container that will get copied out to the production .app file when the application is run.
4. Inside that **objects** folder in your project folder, create a **qml** folder.
5. Download the files from this location into that **qml** folder, and be sure to unzip that zip download.

https://github.com/jwintz/qchart.js

6. Create a **bar.qml** file in that same **qml** directory. The contents of that file should look like so:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

import "."
import "QChart.js"        as Charts
import "QChartGallery.js" as ChartsData

Chart {
  id: chart_bar;
  width: 450;
  height: 450;
  chartAnimated: false;
  chartData: ChartsData.ChartBarData;
  chartType: Charts.ChartType.BAR;
}
```

7. In your **mainwindow.cpp**, add this in your `main()` function sometime after you do the `ui->setupUi(this);` line:

```
QString sQMLPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath().append("/objects/qml/bar.qml");
ui->quickWidget->setSource(QString("file://").append(sQMLPath));
```

This will ensure that your QML file has the proper path when it is deployed in production (or
       debug).

> Note: I tried loading these QML and JS files via a Qt Resource (qrc:// pathing), but it didn't seem to properly like that and complained either about not finding the QChart.qml file or a message that "QChart is not a type".

8. When you run your application, you should see a bar chart. You can then study the [chart.js website](http://www.chartjs.org/) for more info on how to manipulate this chart.

Answer (score 1):

There are some implementations of the [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) library for QML available on [github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=qml+chart). The most popular is probably [the one by Julien Wintz](https://github.com/jwintz/qchart.js). I once tried it out but didn't find a way to set up mouse interaction with individual charts/bars inside the QML canvas element and also the performance was not the best for bigger data sets. For the best solution you'll have to write your own chart library which should not be too much work (depending on your requirements of course).

<strike>If Qt enterprise edition is an option,</strike> go with [QtCharts](http://doc.qt.io/QtCharts/qtcharts-qmlchart-example.html).

**Update:** Since Qt 5.7, Qt Charts will be available as a part of Qt with GPL license: https://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/16/qt-5-7-released/

Comment: Looks promising, but the documentation is really poor. I don't know how to get this installed.

Comment: Julien Wintz's version is offline. And QtCharts is indeed offered as GPL *BUT NOT* LGPL, which is needed for closed-source commercial software. There are so far only Chart Js implementations vor v1.0.x available, not 2.0, sadly

Answer (score 1):

Try: https://gist.github.com/paulbendixen/f14cd848a3f89a38ef37

The legend can be turned on and off and you can put any data in it as long as it has the value, color and legend parts.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a lib that integrates a JS library to do the drawing. We have worked on this MIT-license version, which you can use with GPL, LGPL or a closed-source project. Maybe, it's interesting for you, too: https://github.com/Elypson/ChartJs2QML